# How to block Yandex and Baidu IPs in GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine

In robots.txt I can put:

```
#Baiduspider
User-agent: Baiduspider
Disallow: /

#Yandex
User-agent: Yandex
Disallow: /
```

to tell the search engines to stop crawling my app pages (php app). But how to block them by IPs in GAE?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways.

1. Do it in your code.
2. Use the DOS facilities  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/dos

Comment: I rather not do it in the code since that would consume instance hours, which is the reason why I am blocking those two search engines.  I will try blacklisting them in dos.yaml and see if that works for my php app